# Promela - non-determinism not non-deterministic?

Tags: verification, non-deterministic, spin, promela

Consider this snippet:

```
chan sel = [0] of {int};

active proctype Selector(){
    int not_me;

    endselector:
    do
    ::  sel ? not_me;
        if
        :: 0 != not_me -> sel ! 0;
        :: 1 != not_me -> sel ! 1;
        :: 2 != not_me -> sel ! 2;
        :: 3 != not_me -> sel ! 3;
        :: else -> -1;
        fi

    od
}

proctype H(){
    int i = -1;
    int count = 1000;
    do
    :: sel ! i; sel ? i; printf("currently selected: %d\n",i); count = count -1;
    :: count < 0 -> break;
    od

    assert(false);
}

init{
    atomic{
        run H();
    }
}
```

You'd expect this to print pretty the values 0..3 pretty arbitrarily until the counter falls below 0, at which point it can either print another number or it will terminate.

However, that doesn't seem to be the case.

The only values returned are 0, then 1, then 0, then 1, then 0, then 1, ...

Did I somehow misunderstand the "non-determinism" of the if/fi statements?

(using ispin on ubuntu, if that matters).

Answer (score 1):

[Relevant part of language spec](http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/if.html). Seems non-determinstic to me.

If you're looking at (a few) traces of the system only, then you're at the mercy of the (pseudo) random generator.

I thought the main purpose of SPIN is to prove properties. So, you could write a formula F that describes the trace(s) that you want, and then have SPIN check that "system and F" has a model.

Comment: You could also try running it in interactive mode and see if all the non-deterministic options are enabled

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Spin in 'simulation' mode, then the `else` options are visited deterministically, I believe.  So in the `Selector` proctype, the simulation proceeds in the `if` by checking the options as: 0 ~= not_me and then the 1, 2, 3 options.  For your execution, you thus ping pong between 0 and 1.

You can confirm this, by replacing your `if` statement with:

```
if
:: 0 != not_me -> sel ! 0;
:: 1 != not_me -> sel ! 1;
:: else -> assert(false)
fi
```

and your simulation will never reach the assert.

Spin can also be run in 'verification' mode - generate a `pan` executable and execute that.  Then, all cases will be visited (modulo limits in memory and time).  However, in 'verification' mode nothing is printed out - so you might be hard pressed to see the other cases!